# Proof of uniqueness of the extension in Kolmogorov extension theorem

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

[Statement of the theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_existence_theorem).

The proof is mainly focused on showing that the candidate probability measure defined on the algebra of sets is $\sigma $-additive.

At the end, the [Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn-Kolmogorov_theorem) is used to obtain the unique extension to the $\sigma $-algebra generated from that algebra of sets.

However, one of the conditions of the Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem states that the candidate probability measure defined on the algebra of sets should be $\sigma $-finite for that extension to be unique, but in the proof it's assumed that this condition is obvious since there is no mention of it.

How does one see that the candidate probability measure on the algebra of sets is $\sigma $-finite?

Let me know if I should provide more details about the proof in question.

Comment: A probability measure is finite, not to mention $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Right, I don't know how it didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better to recall the [Caratheodory Extension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_extension_theorem) and definition of $\sigma$-finite. As you know $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite if there exist a measurable sets $\Omega_{1} \subset \Omega_{2}... $ such that union of all $\Omega_{i} =\Omega $ and $\mu (\Omega) < \infty $. By the Caratheodory Extension Theorem if $\mu_0$ is not $\sigma$-finite then the extension need not be unique, even if the extension itself is $\sigma$ - finite. if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite then use the Caratheodory Extension Theorem and you will get extension is unique.